# can you whitelist urls with haproxy?

Tags: url-rewriting, reverse-proxy, haproxy, whitelist, blacklist

Hello I want to white list certain urls in haproxy such as

Only foobar.com/mypages/*  can be accessible.

Anything else under foobar.com should be blocked.

Does haproxy give you the capability to do that?

Thanks,
Bob

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following configuration to get the desired result :

```
#Will set the ACL if path matches
acl allowed_url path_reg */mypages/*

#Based on the previouslt set ACL , we can reject or allow connections
#Accept/whitelist if matches
tcp_request connection accept if allowed_url
#Reject if not
tcp_request connection reject if !allowed_url
```

There are other path matching ACL directives: [Path-directives](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.5/configuration.html#7.3.6-path).Use the one which suits your case best.